# Why are there fake Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, clone, copycat-sites

I recently came across these links doing a search on Google:

> [How to expand selection to include enclosing element in Sublime Text 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/668730/how-to-expand-selection-to-include-enclosing-element-in-sublime-text-3)
>
> http://earthwithsun.com/questions/668730/how-to-expand-selection-to-include-enclosing-element-in-sublime-text-3

Can't Stack Exchange do something about this? It's obvious that `earthwithsun.com` copied data from `superuser.com`.

Comment: I wonder if anybody asks "Why is there a real StackExchange site" on those fake sites.

Comment: On `earthwithsun` you can't really post a question, or reply, or anything, but funny comment :))